# Using numerous IP addresses in a browser in linux

Tags: proxy, ip, address

I own a dedicated server than runs Debian Linux. I have 64 IP addresses configured on the machine. I am looking to open a page (just has to access it with lynx or anything to read) with one of the non-default 64 IP addresses, besides just the default one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a similar thing recently with firefox.  I used this code
http://www.ryde.net/code/bind.c.txt Which changes which IP address the OS uses for new processes.

It might be one way to do this. Neither links nor Lynx seems to have any --bind-address command line argument, like wget does.

That said, you could just use curl and pipe the output to something more sensible. `curl --interface eth0 http://www.google.com`

Comment: wget --bind-address command line  is what I wanted. Thanks.